# how to retrieve the data from arraylist that is passed statically in android?

Tags: android

I am passing my **array list data statically from one page to other page in android**. For the first time when I executed the application I am getting the array list data statically to the second page. I kept a home button at the top in the second page. I clicked on the home button and started from 1st page again. This time I am not getting the arraylist data to the second page. I am clearing the arraylist in home button click action. **But why is the data not coming for the second time**. Please help me with this issue....I am struggling for this a lot....

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you please post your code ?

Comment: Hello Chirag Raval, Don't add same comment in one question, this is not good.

Answer (score 0):

When you clear the ArrayList, how will you get the data? Either don't clear it or pass a Bundle in the Intent to transfer the List.

Comment: Hi I am clearing the arraylist in second page and again starting from first page...so first page will be called again na...then again the new data will be stored in the arraylist...but it is not getting to the second page the second time

Answer (score 0):

Use Iterator... without the use of iterator , u cannot implement multiple retrival....